# How to auto sort the list of subsites in the Quick Launch on an Office 365 SharePoint?

Tags: office-365, managed-navigation

On our SharePoint config we've got a subsite for each client that we pick up.  When creating we select to display the site on the Quick Launch of the parent, which works exactly as expected. Except ... that the sites aren't in alphabetical order. Is there any way to automatically sort the list in SharePoint online? Everything I'm finding when I Google is about SharePoint on-prem.

Comment: Have a look this link: http://my365support.com/tag/quick-launch/

Comment: That's just to add a link, we're looking to automatically sort the links.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here hopes it helps you out - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-Quick-Launch-for-site-navigation-d3288963-4a91-4470-9192-610952daecdf . As per the requirement i think this should resolve your problem which you have asked.

Comment: Sadly that's for SharePoint 2010 not Office 365.